# Fortran natural logarithm error

Tags: fortran, logarithm, fortran95

New to Fortran (just started today), having trouble with the natural logarithm:

```
PROGRAM log
IMPLICIT NONE
REAL :: x

PRINT *, "Enter a number:"
READ *, x

x = log (x)

PRINT *, "The natural log of x is:", x

END PROGRAM log
```

The compiler keeps throwing up the error:

```
x = log (x)
       1
Error: Symbol at (1) is not appropriate for an expression
```

Other intrinsic functions work fine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you've shadowed (overridden) the definition of the symbol `log` - which would normally refer to the standard library mathematical function - with the name of your program, which is also `log`.   If you change the name of the program to, say, `logtest`:

```
PROGRAM logtest
...
END PROGRAM logtest
```

You'll find that the program works as expected.

Comment: No, not at all, it's not something that would happen in most other languages (the shadowing, yes, but not with the program name).   Most languages don't even have program names.

Comment: funny, this had me stumped -- I guess since I haven't used a PROGRAM statement since 1985.. Do they serve a purpose other than taking one symbol out of your namespace?

Comment: I think it's only for clarity; the shortest valid fortran is "`end`". The error message gfortran gives here is a little puzzling though.

Comment: It's like naming loops or conditionals - it's just for clarity and so that the compiler can give you clearer errors when you "end" the wrong thing.   But yes, it's a serious limitation that there's only one namespace for symbols.